# What does this scale mean?

Tags: physical-chemistry, concentration, units

[image]

$$\log_{10}~\mathrm{pg}/\mathrm{ml}$$

I do not understand the scale.  How do I convert this to a standard concentration (without the logs)?

Comment: It's just http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_scale you can easily switch to numbers by calculating log10 of number, pg/ml stay as is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To expand upon the comments, the y axis in this graph is simply the log of the concentration in pg/ml.  To convert you use the equation $$C = 10^{y}$$ where y is the y value and C is the concentration.  Note that in older literature, log was oftentimes assumed to be base e whereas nowadays we assume base 10.  The figure (thankfully) clarifies this potential discrepancy.

A final note: log values are *unitless* so the y axis has no units.  The units are reported here so that you know what the appropriate units of the converted value should be.